# My touchpad is unresponsive; is it dying?

Tags: linux, hardware-failure, gentoo, synaptics-touchpad

The touchpad on my laptop appears to be no longer functioning. I typically use an external keyboard and mouse, so I didn't notice the problem until I tried to use the touchpad. I'm running Gentoo Linux.

Even after I toggled the on/off switch several times, the touchpad still wouldn't work.

I saw something in the logs about `cannot read byte from synaptics device`. I will post the full logs when I am in front of my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure that you drivers are up-to-date. If they are, then uninstall and reinstall the drivers. This may fix everything. Drivers can get corrupted from time to time.

-Good Luck!

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try ... I have everything under version control, so I will first check to see if any drivers changed recently.

Comment: Hmm, I now only see this in my Xorg log file ... 32.875] (EE) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad no synaptics event device found.  I am guessing something died.  I am looking through my repository for recent changes to drivers and have a lot of changes to sort through ...

Comment: I read somewhere that there was an issue with the kernel version I am on that should be addressed in ck sources.

Comment: @WalterWhite I am glad that your touchpad is fixed! Thank you for accepting my answer.